# Proposing new silver answer badge: Excellent answer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badge-request

- Answer score of 25 or more
- Answer is accepted
- *Answer has a single revision.*

In other words, you answered accurately, no edits were required, OP accepted it => **Excellent answer**.

Elaborating based on the comments:

1. How long do you have to keep a single revision before you get awarded this, and if it gets edited after you've got the badge, does it get revoked?

   As soon as you meet the 3 criteria, you get the badge. 
   A badge never gets revoked, so later edits will no longer count.
2. Good answer is already a silver badge.. If at all there needs to be a badge for answers with higher score shouldnt it be gold?

   The definition for gold badge is *Gold badges recognize important contributions from members of the community. They are rarely awarded.* I didn't feel my proposed badge is such an important contribution to be gold.
3. Why do you feel this badge is necessary - what behaviour would it encourage for instance?

   Are all badges trying to encourage something? Think of tumbleweed badge. 
   This badge aims at rewarding a super accurate answer that didn't need any edits.
4. An answer can be revised for any number of reasons.. not necessary that it is bad or poor... It might need to be updated at a later point of time. You might end up discouraging users from doing so

   I overlooked this. Indeed it might discourage people from bringing improvements where needed, just to keep it at 1 revision to get the badge. If the proposal gets declined, this reason alone should suffice :)
5. What about edits in the grace period? What if someone else edits it? The whole "no edits" thing seems kind of arbitrary

   If someone else edits it, is it still a single revision?

The point of the request is to give another challenge and to reward super accurate answers that didn't even need an edit

Comment: How long do you have to keep a single revision before you get awarded this, and if it gets edited after you've got the badge, does it get revoked? Seems to me this will only discourage people from making edits...

Comment: Good answer is _already_ a silver badge.. _If at all_ there needs to be a badge for answers with higher score shouldnt it be gold?

Comment: A badge never gets revoked

Comment: Gotta agree with @JonClements on this one, just seems like the [Good Question Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/21/good-question) with a bad addition

Comment: @SurajRao - The definition for gold badge is *Gold badges recognize important contributions from members of the community. They are rarely awarded.*

Comment: @Adelin so at what point does it get deemed it's never been edited? It's just not particularly feasible criteria even if you could put across a great argument as to why it's needed... Why do you feel this badge is necessary - what behaviour would it encourage for instance? Why would the site want to implement this badge etc...?

Comment: @SurajRao FWIW, Guru is also a silver badge.

Comment: If you reach 25 score, it's accepted and you have a single revision - you get the badge. Then the answer can be edited, but you don't lose the badge. While I think we should somehow reward such an answer, that didn't get edited, I overlooked the fact that it might discourage edits in the first place - that's not the point my proposal.

Comment: @Glorfindel yes.. but [Good Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/24/good-answer) covers a part of OP's conditions

Comment: I don't think this -in any way- improves the quality of answers / site.

Comment: @Adelin an answer can be revised for any number of reasons.. not necessary that it is _bad_ or _poor_... It might need to be _updated_ at a later point of time. You might end up discouraging users from doing so

Comment: What about edits in the grace period? What if someone else edits it? The whole "no edits" thing seems kind of arbitrary.

Comment: @ivarni - if someone else edits it, is it still a single revision? come on... I agree that an answer might need updates, and that edits are a good thing - the point of the request is to give another challenge and to reward super accurate answers that didn't even need an edit

Comment: There's tons of pointless edits being done here every day, so lets assume for a second an edit is rolled back, how would the system handle that? It would technically be the 3rd revision even though it looks exactly like it did when posted. I understand what you're trying to achieve but I just think it's not really a good metric.

Comment: Going beyond the technical problems of implementing this, badges should encourage desirable behavior.

What behavior would this badge encourage that existing badges do not? The only difference lies in the "no edits" part, which I do not think it's a desirable thing.

Comment: Actually, Good answer badge needs the same score not lower than your proposal... I was mistaken in my first comment. You just added another condition to it

Comment: Tumbleweed is a _bronze_ badge. And not a great one at that. It's a funny curiosity that you are never happy to get awarded. More like a consolation prize. Not a badge model to follow.

Comment: I can only downvote this in its current state, most answers I've seen that I would label "excellent" needed many revisions to get there and there is nothing wrong with that. I get the idea behind this but rather than excellence the name should be more to do with accuracy.

Comment: I think the development of the posts should be encouraged and not discouraged, thus I disagree the proposal, but I much more disagree the people who voted this initiative down. You should have voted up the rejecting answer! You don't understand, what the votes mean! Downvoting the question means, that "it is not an useful question", which is ortogonal to that you agree it or not!

Comment: I think its nearly exact opposite (honoring with badges late edits to answers which got many upvotes after that) would be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, really, we don't need or should want this badge. We have plenty of answer badges, and this badge goes counter to what we would want to encourage.

We already have plenty of answer badges. A well written, well received answer can net you 2 bronze, 4 silver and 3 gold badges, depending on when it was posted, the acceptance status and the score of the question<sup>*</sup>:

- bronze:

  - Nice Answer
  - Revival
- silver

  - Enlightened
  - Good Answer
  - Guru
  - Necromancer
- gold

  - Great Answer
  - Reversal
  - Populist

One well-placed answer could get you up to 9 badges at a time (Populist is mutually exclusive with Enlightened and Guru, but in theory you can earn all 3 for one answer if the acceptance status was changed at some point). All of these together reward you for provide accurate answers already.

But more importantly, your proposed badge *discourages editing your answer*. This goes counter to what we want to achieve, which is high-quality *up to date and relevant* answers.

Badges exist to encourage certain behaviour. We don't need badges that try to prevent behaviour we want to encourage.

---

<sup>*</sup>: These are all badges that can be awarded more than once. The other badges that are tied to answering are all single-shot badges.

Comment: Good points - but don't you think that it would be an even greater answer if it would meet all those conditions and still be at the first revision? Thus the user who posted the answer deserves to be rewarded for that?

Comment: @Adelin: sure, but we don't want to *encourage* that behaviour.

Comment: @Adelin: "*but don't you think that it would be an even greater answer if it would meet all those conditions and still be at the first revision?*" No. I don't see how the number or revisions correlates with the quality of the answer as it *currently* stands.

Comment: @NicolBolas you are fixated on “quality”. It’s not about the quality, it’s about “nailing it from the first try”.

Comment: @Adelin may have to do with the name of the badge? 'Excellent' definitely sounds like a measure of quality. Maybe if the name was 'bullseye' or something, to emphasize the accuracy part? I am not saying I would agree with the badge either way. But it would take the focus away from quality and into accuracy,  I believe

Comment: @Patrice you are right. I should've specified that that's flexible and not set in stone :)

Answer (score 4):

> You are fixated on “quality”. It’s not about the quality, it’s about “nailing it from the first try”.

Yes, I am fixated on quality. Almost all of the existing answer badges measures some aspect of either the quality of the answer or some way that the answer improves things on the site measurably:

- Nice/Good/Great Answer: Upvotes are supposed to indicate quality.
- Revival: Providing good content to old, unanswered questions improves the site.
- Guru: Highly upvoted and accepted answers suggest that the answer is of high merit.
- Necromancer: If you add an answer to an old question and get upvotes for it, you're clearly providing good content to an old question. That's a good thing which improves the site.
- Populist: Proof that the accepted answer is not always the right one. Having such a highly upvoted answer makes the site better, even if it's not the first answer on the question.

The only ones that you could argue don't gauge quality/site improvement are Reversal (rewards answering poor questions) and Enlightened (rewards answering first, not best). Notably, these are the most controversial answer badges.

Your hypothetical badge is much the same. It's a reward for something that doesn't make the site better. It doesn't matter how many revisions it took to get good content. What matters is if it is good content.

Comment: *The site better. Good content* what about user’s efforts?

Comment: @Adelin: What about them?

Comment: Well, it's pointless to keep reiterating if you are fixated on quality, and quality alone :)

Comment: @Adelin: it doesn't matter what effort the user puts in. What matters is the *output, the actual answers*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I can see that this is the perception. However, it's not always true. For example it's not acceptable to take an answer from one place and paste it in another - even if it's a great answer - you just stole *someone else's* efforts.

Comment: @Adelin: "*Well, it's pointless to keep reiterating if you are fixated on quality, and quality alone*" Quality is why the site exists. It is you who needs to explain why we should reward people for something *other than* quality. How does rewarding people for getting it right the first time improve the site? And if it doesn't improve the site, why should we add things that don't improve the site?

Comment: @NicolBolas you fail to understand that I don't propose to reward something *other* than quality, but to applaud someone who was capable of bringing plenty of quality without needing a lot of back and forth modifications (edits).

Comment: @Adelin: Badges are rewards, so you are rewarding something other than quality. You need to explain why this is worthy of such a reward.

Comment: @Adelin: yes, you can't go put your name on content that wasn't yours to begin with. If you are going to reward people for the content they contributed, ownership *is* important. But we don't care if they took a single try to get an answer right, or 10.

Comment: @MartijnPieters maybe *you* don't care but it made OP feel good. In other words, as of now, 24 users don't care, 1 cares (shockingly, I have one upvote)

Comment: @NicolBolas *How does rewarding people for getting it right the first time improve the site? And if it doesn't improve the site, why should we add things that don't improve the site?* By rewarding people, you improve the site. You make it a nice env for them - they feel good here - they strive to be better and better.

Comment: @Adelin: "*By rewarding people, you improve the site.*" Nonsense. Rewards are encouragement. If you encourage someone to do something that isn't improving the site, then you get more people doing that thing. And since it's not improving the site by them doing it, then you get more people spending time in irrelevant ways. That's not improving the site.

Comment: I am tired of this argument. I understand that people might avoid edits due to this badge and it’s a bad idea - and I accept that. Let’s stop this opinionated conversation. I’m not able to convince you and you’re not able to convince me.